# MapBox geocoder results are not exact, how to enhance mapbox geocoding API?

Tags: geocoding, mapbox

We are trying to get the address related data (ex. site address, city, state, country, postal code, lat-long) 
of a particular site from the MapBox geocoding API, through geocoding and reverse-geocoding and populate it into form fields. We are using the autocomplete address search field for the same. but it is observed that whenever the user tries to search few sites with the help of autocomplete address search field the geocoding API does not return exact address or even related address into its suggested address dropdown (especially for sites in Poland, UK).

It will be great if someone could suggest any solution to enhance the geocoding API functionality so that a user can search address of any site
can we also design our own dataset and use it into geocoding API to enhance the API functionality. so that all the required 
site address will be readily available for the user whenever he/she uses the autocomplete address search field (geocoding API)

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you're using mapbox-gl-geocoder or just accessing the API directly. If the former https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/pull/123 is one option to supplement the geocoder with your own local results/data.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Harvey for the quick reply. FYI we are using Mapbox.js (L.mapbox.geocoderControl) .basically the issue is that when the end user is using the Autocomplete address field to get the data related to the address, the results returned by API in the drop-down  of the Autocomplete address field are inaccurate and we are finding a way to enhance this functionality